# Calling an array from one class onto another

Tags: java, arrays, swing, 2d

I am creating a snakes and ladders game. My issue is that I have two classes, one the main GUI in a JFrame for the game with an image of a snakes and ladders board, and the other a 2D array of a grid which I want to superimpose over the board game, so the squares in the image match the squares of the grid.

I figure I need to call it as an instance of the Grid class, but I cant seem to get it to work (or perhaps, placed in the correct position!). Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

GameBoard class:

```
public class GameBoard extends javax.swing.JFrame {
private JLabel Board;
private JLabel playerNumber;
private ButtonGroup group;
private JButton startButton;
private JRadioButton fourPlayer;
private JRadioButton threePlayer;
private JRadioButton twoPlayer;


/**
* Auto-generated main method to display this JFrame
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            GameBoard inst = new GameBoard();
            inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            inst.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public GameBoard() {
    super();
    initGUI();
}

private void initGUI() {
    try {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        {
            Board = new JLabel();
            getContentPane().add(Board);
            Board.setText("jLabel1");
            Board.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/board.jpg")));
            Board.setBounds(199, 0, 742, 484);
        }
        {
            playerNumber = new JLabel();
            getContentPane().add(playerNumber);
            playerNumber.setText("Number of Players");
            playerNumber.setBounds(40, 22, 117, 27);
        }
        {
            twoPlayer = new JRadioButton();
            getContentPane().add(twoPlayer);
            twoPlayer.setText("Two Player");
            twoPlayer.setBounds(40, 55, 93, 20);
        }
        {
            threePlayer = new JRadioButton();
            getContentPane().add(threePlayer);
            threePlayer.setText("Three Players");
            threePlayer.setBounds(40, 76, 88, 20);
        }
        {
            fourPlayer = new JRadioButton();
            getContentPane().add(fourPlayer);
            fourPlayer.setText("Four Players");
            fourPlayer.setBounds(40, 99, 82, 20);
        }
        {
            startButton = new JButton();
            getContentPane().add(startButton);
            startButton.setText("Start Game");
            startButton.setBounds(43, 136, 83, 23);
        }

        {
         //Group the radio buttons.
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(twoPlayer);
        group.add(threePlayer);
        group.add(fourPlayer);
        }

        pack();
        this.setSize(963, 523);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //add your error handling code here
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }



}

;
```

Grid class:

```
public class Grid {

int[][] multi = {
        {0,0,-1,0,0,-1,0,-1,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
        {0,-1,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,1},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0},
        {0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0}
};
```

}

Comment: Yes, I guess `GameBoard` needs an instance of `Grid`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that `GameBoard` will need an instance `Grid` in order for it to know where to place the game pieces.

You could change `GameBoard` so that it required an instance of `Grid` to be passed to it...

```
public class GameBoard extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    //...
    private Grid grid;
    public GameBoard(Grid grid) {
        this.grid = grid;
        //...
```

Then create and pass an instance of `Grid` when you create an instance of `GameBoard`...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Grid grid = new Grid();
            GameBoard inst = new GameBoard(grid);
            inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            inst.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

But, I'd also add some functionality to `Grid` to control how it's modified, but that's me

> I cant seem to get it work using your original method. I would like to just simply create an instance but for the life of me I can't seem to get it working

Seems to work okay for me...

```
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class GameBoard extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private JLabel Board;
    private JLabel playerNumber;
    private ButtonGroup group;
    private JButton startButton;
    private JRadioButton fourPlayer;
    private JRadioButton threePlayer;
    private JRadioButton twoPlayer;

    private Grid grid;

    /**
     * Auto-generated main method to display this JFrame
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Grid grid = new Grid();
                GameBoard inst = new GameBoard(grid);
                inst.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                inst.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public GameBoard(Grid grid) {
        super();
        this.grid = grid;
        initGUI();
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        try {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            getContentPane().setLayout(null);
            {
                Board = new JLabel();
                getContentPane().add(Board);
                Board.setText("jLabel1");
                Board.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/board.jpg")));
                Board.setBounds(199, 0, 742, 484);
            }
            {
                playerNumber = new JLabel();
                getContentPane().add(playerNumber);
                playerNumber.setText("Number of Players");
                playerNumber.setBounds(40, 22, 117, 27);
            }
            {
                twoPlayer = new JRadioButton();
                getContentPane().add(twoPlayer);
                twoPlayer.setText("Two Player");
                twoPlayer.setBounds(40, 55, 93, 20);
            }
            {
                threePlayer = new JRadioButton();
                getContentPane().add(threePlayer);
                threePlayer.setText("Three Players");
                threePlayer.setBounds(40, 76, 88, 20);
            }
            {
                fourPlayer = new JRadioButton();
                getContentPane().add(fourPlayer);
                fourPlayer.setText("Four Players");
                fourPlayer.setBounds(40, 99, 82, 20);
            }
            {
                startButton = new JButton();
                getContentPane().add(startButton);
                startButton.setText("Start Game");
                startButton.setBounds(43, 136, 83, 23);
            }

            {
                //Group the radio buttons.
                ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
                group.add(twoPlayer);
                group.add(threePlayer);
                group.add(fourPlayer);
            }

            pack();
            this.setSize(963, 523);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //add your error handling code here
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: As an example...You could also use a setter method or simply create an instance of `Grid` inside of `GameBoard`, but I like the ability to pass a new `Grid` to the `GameBoard`

Comment: I cant seem to get it work using your original method. I would like to just simply create an instance but for the life of me I can't seem to get it working

Comment: Thats the code I used and whilst it compiles fine, next to `Private Grid grid;` it says 'the value of the field GameBoard.grid is not used'?

Comment: Yeah, have you used it anywhere, other then assigning it?

Comment: Sorry if I sound silly, its late and my minds wandering! No, I dont think I have, i simply want to use the grid to be able to move my counters throughout each square, as if they were actually on the snakes and ladders board (which is just an image). - Does that even make sense haha? I've marked the question as answered however as you have done so

Comment: I'm not sure how you intend to place you players on the screen, but the use of the `Grid` to map things out is a good start.  You now have an instance of `Grid` to move you onto the next step :)